# Why doesn't setuptools setup.py clean the build directory?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm new to Python packaging.

If you build a package, then remove a file from the source, then build a package again, the now non-existing file still gets included in the newly-built package. This appears to be because the build directory doesn't get cleaned before building.

Presumably this isn't a bug, but how/why is it considered a "feature"?

This is using `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and `setuptools`